# Service Bus Disposed Object

Tags: .net, azure, message-queue, servicebus

I am using message queue architecture on Azure through Service Bus. Occasionally when I attempt to send a message to the queue it fails. Here is the Error I get:

Sometimes I get this message

```
Message:Can't create session when the connection is closing.
```

Other times i get this message

```
Message:Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1'.
```

Keep in mind that it doesnt happen all the time. Sometimes I am creating thousands of messages for the service buss. I am dispatching an async task for each message I send to the queue

Here is my code

```
Task.Run(() => new ServiceBusService().SendQueueMessage(busMessageObject));
```

ServiceBus Class

```
public class ServiceBusService
{ 
    static string ServiceBusConnectionString = AzureUtils.SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTIONSTRING;
    const string QueueName = "eventqueue";
    static IQueueClient queueClient;

    public async Task SendQueueMessage(JObject jObject, DateTime? scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = null)
    {
        string jsonObject = "";
        string scheduledTime = "";

        if(scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc.HasValue)
        {
            scheduledTime = scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc.Value.ToLongTimeString();
        }

        try
        {
            queueClient = new QueueClient(ServiceBusConnectionString, QueueName);
            var message = new Message(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jObject.ToString()));

            if(scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc.HasValue)
                message.ScheduledEnqueueTimeUtc = scheduledEnqueueTimeUtc.Value;

            await queueClient.SendAsync(message);
            await queueClient.CloseAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Trace.TraceError($"{Tag()} " + e.InnerException + " " + e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It was because my QueueClient was static and multiple threads were using it, and disposing it. Making it not static solved my issue.

Comment: Is there any consequences by removing static ! I am having the  error !!                   
Azure service bus error + Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'ServiceBusConnection has already been closed. Please create a new instance'.

Comment: I am building an HL7 interface listener.  This is exactly what happened to my code for Azure Event Hub code from MS documentation, it was a static class, after I changed to a regular class the error went away.  Thanks so much.

Comment: Might have changed now then as they write about having clients as singletons: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/azure-sdk/lifetime-management-and-thread-safety-guarantees-of-azure-sdk-net-clients/