# Azure ServiceBus FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1' Exception

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus

So I have upgraded to the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus version 7.1.2 and my project to .NET 4.7.2 due to the need for TLS 1.2. I rewrote the listener (that is an on prem windows service) like so  `BusListener.cs` :

```
public static async Task ReceiveMessagesAsync()
    {   
        await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING]))
        {
            ServiceBusProcessor processor = client.CreateProcessor(QUEUE_NAME, new ServiceBusProcessorOptions());

            processor.ProcessMessageAsync += MessageHandler;
            processor.ProcessErrorAsync += ErrorHandler;

            await processor.StartProcessingAsync();
        }
    }
```

That I call in my windows service `ServiceMain.cs`

```
Task.Run(() => BusListener.ReceiveMessagesAsync());
```

I get this error after about 10s of waiting and no message is ever received:

```
Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'FaultTolerantAmqpObject`1'. - at Microsoft.Azure.Amqp.Singleton`1.d__13.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.Amqp.AmqpConnectionScope.d__54.MoveNext()
```

I looked around and it looked like from this other answer: [Service Bus Disposed Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55764374/service-bus-disposed-object) that I could be running into issues due to the method being static, even though this is what I'm following in the Microsoft "how to" guide here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-dotnet-get-started-with-queues

I'm unsure if I'm writing the service bus part incorrectly or it's something else I'm missing? Is there a way to just ping or test connectivity to get a better idea of what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a `ServiceBusClient`, it owns the connection to the service used by any child objects that it creates.  By disposing the client in this line:

```cs
await using (ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[SERVICE_BUS_CONNECTION_STRING]))
```

You're closing the connection used by the processor that you've created.  I'd recommend hoisting the client out of the method and allowing it to exist as a singleton for the lifetime of your application.  Generally speaking, that is the approach that we recommend for managing Azure clients.  *(see: [client lifetime](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus#client-lifetime))*

Comment: I'll take a follow-up to get that sample updated, as it's demonstrating an anti-pattern.